# Can someone show me how to set up log4j for jruby on rails on Tomcat?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tomcat, log4j, jruby

I follow several direction and none of them seems to be working.  Here are my specific question.
1.  What jars to include in lib directory?
2.  Where should I put the log4j.properties?  What it should look like?
3.  How did rails know to use log4j?  None of the direction mentioned that I need to change environment.rb or environments/production.rb to change the logger configuration.  How did rails know to use log4j?  Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. Just the log4j jar should be enough, AFAIK.
2. In WEB-INF/classes. See log4j documentation for details.
3. To tell Rails about log4j, set the context init parameter `jruby.rack.logging` to `log4j`:

   <context-param>
       <param-name>jruby.rack.logging</param-name>
       <param-value>log4j</param-value>
     </context-param>

Then JRuby-Rack will set the Rails logger to use log4j at startup.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.  I have done all 3 steps but still not working.

Comment: Ah, I found out my problem is.  The log4j.properties file must be in the root directory WEB-INF/classes.  I put in in WEB-INF/classes/lib.  Thanks Nick.  It works now. Thanks for helping me.